# Concatenating an Array Text

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, pg

how to add a TEXT within an Array?

```
var_result text[];
var_result_valor text;
var_legenda text;

var_result_valor := '2.34';
var_legenda := 'Baixo';
```

Thus giving this error:

```
var_result := [var_result_valor,var_legenda]
```

Comment: what if you try to do like: `var_result := ['2.34','Baixo']`

Comment: Resulting error: error sintase "["

Comment: you should to use a ARRAY keyword: result := ARRAY['a','b'];

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var_result_valor := '2.34';
var_legenda := 'Baixo';
var_result[1]:=var_result_valor;
var_result[2]:=var_legenda;
```

Here is the current arrays [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html).